# Is there a way to increment a semaphore and decrement another one atomically in POSIX?

Tags: c, posix, ipc, semaphore, posix-api

Is there a way to do multiple increments / decrements on distinct semaphores in one (atomic) operation?

I saw that in SysV it is possible to do this and I was wondering if there was a way to do the same using POSIX API.

Here's what I would like to do (in SysV):

```
  sem[0].sem_num = 0;
  sem[0].sem_op  = 1;
  sem[0].sem_flg = 0;

  sem[1].sem_num = 1;
  sem[1].sem_op  = -1;
  sem[1].sem_flg = 0;

  semop(semid, sem, 2)
```

Is there a way to do the same in POSIX?

Comment: Posix has `semop()`

Comment: After you edit, still, [`semop()` is posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/semop.html). If you're wondering about `XSI`, quoting the standard `Application writers may confidently make use of an extension on all systems supporting the X/Open System Interfaces Extension`. Do you have an actual system where you have `semaphore.h` but do not have XSI semaphores? Could you share what system is that?

Comment: Or is it that you simply want to use `<semaphore.h>` semaphores instead of the XSI ones (for their other features, or to match existing code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to do same using `semaphore.h`?

No, it is not possible.

> Is there a way to do the same *in POSIX*?

The code you posted is using XSI extension to POSIX. Generally, even the standard states that if you are on POSIX compatible platform, you may use XSI extension with confidence that it will be available.